# Сложная анимация на react js. правильный способ/подход

Tags: reactjs, анимация

Привет!
Какой способ/подход для сложной анимации в приложении на react js корректен?
Я знаю про transition group. Но что если нужна сложная анимация в 1 компоненте, допустим передвижение svg маски через drag&drop или анимация по tick() других элементов на странице в d3.js с кучей побочных анимационных эффектов?
Какой способ реализации данных задач будет наиболее правильным с точки зрения react? кроме как прикрутить jquery + jquery transit идей больше нет. Нагуглить развёрнутую инфу так и не удалось. Help!
Данная проблема не касается таких вещей как webgl/canvas. Именно анимация DOM элементов в react, когда transition group уже не хватает или делать с помощью этой библиотеки крайне не удобно.

Answer (score 1):

В работе с d3.js приветствуется такая конструкция:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import { scaleLinear } from 'd3-scale’
import { max } from 'd3-array'
import { select } from 'd3-selection'
class BarChart extends Component {
   constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.createBarChart = this.createBarChart.bind(this)
   }
   componentDidMount() {
      this.createBarChart()
   }
   componentDidUpdate() {
      this.createBarChart()
   }
   createBarChart() {
      const node = this.node
      const dataMax = max(this.props.data)
      const yScale = scaleLinear()
         .domain([0, dataMax])
         .range([0, this.props.size[1]])
   select(node)
      .selectAll('rect')
      .data(this.props.data)
      .enter()
      .append('rect')

   select(node)
      .selectAll('rect')
      .data(this.props.data)
      .exit()
      .remove()

   select(node)
      .selectAll('rect')
      .data(this.props.data)
      .style('fill', '#fe9922')
      .attr('x', (d,i) => i * 25)
      .attr('y', d => this.props.size[1] — yScale(d))
      .attr('height', d => yScale(d))
      .attr('width', 25)
   }
render() {
      return <svg ref={node => this.node = node}
      width={500} height={500}>
      </svg>
   }
}
export default BarChart
```

Еще пример:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import worlddata from './world'
import { geoMercator, geoPath } from 'd3-geo'
class WorldMap extends Component {
   render() {
      const projection = geoMercator()
      const pathGenerator = geoPath().projection(projection)
      const countries = worlddata.features
         .map((d,i) => <path
         key={'path' + i}
         d={pathGenerator(d)}
         className='countries'
         />)
   return <svg width={500} height={500}>
   {countries}
   </svg>
   }
}
export default WorldMap
```